# Problems while Resizing or shrink Cycle2 slide show Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello Stackoverflowers,

First of all thank you for reading this post. I am having a rough time trying to figure out how to make my Cycle 2 slideshow images  shrink and move the images next to the other divs while resizing windows.  The funny thing is that when the slide show has only one png the image moves next to all other divs while resizing, but when I add another image to the slide show all the images stays in its own position and doesn't move with the shrink.

here is my code for the Sector:

```
<div id="clientscont">
  <div class="Title2">Clients</div>

<div id="container">

   <div id="wrapper"> <div class="controller" id="prev2"></div><div class="controller" id="next2"></div></div>


<div id="slider2">  


  <img src="../image1.png" alt="" width="265" height="116" class="logoclient2"/>
  <img src="../image2.png"/>

   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried everything in positioning and display modes and even tried making them separate divs with different attributes....but can't make it work. I really need your help, I thank you all in advance.

*For Cycle I am using jquery

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

changing css attribute to list-Item display solved the issue, it is the only display mode that worked, to solve the bullet problem just changed the font color to the actual background color to hide the bullet.  Now both images stayed centered while shrinking page. The truth is that i don't know the reason of this, if somebody could explain it would be perfect!

ShaloM! and Happy Coding!